# Disable MathJax equation reference link in xaringan slides

Tags: mathjax, xaringan

I've added MathJax equation numbering to my xaringan slides, but the `\eqref{}` (or `\ref{}`) link takes me back to the first slide.  I want to disable the link and remove the link colouring from the reference.

My `.Rmd`

```
---
title: "MathJax test"
output:
  xaringan::moon_reader:
    includes:
      in_header: "mathjax-equation-numbers.html"
    lib_dir: libs
---

\begin{align}
\bar{x} = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{10} x_i \label{my-eq}
\end{align}

An example of an equation is \eqref{my-eq}. Or \ref{my-eq}.
```

My attempt at a solution (not working) in the `mathjax-equation-numbers.html` file:

```
<script type="text/x-mathjax-config">
  MathJax.Hub.Config({
    TeX: { equationNumbers: { autoNumber: "AMS" } },
  "HTML-CSS": {
    styles: {
      ".MathJax a": { color: "black",
                      "pointer-events": "none",
                      cursor: "default",
                      "text-decoration": "none"
      },
      ".MathJax_Preview a": { color: "black",
                      "pointer-events": "none",
                      cursor: "default",
                      "text-decoration": "none"
      },
    }
  }
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try replacing the content of mathjax-equation-numbers.html with below.

```html
<script type="text/x-mathjax-config">
  MathJax.Hub.Config({
    TeX: { equationNumbers: { autoNumber: "AMS" } },
  });
</script>
<style>
.mjx-mrow a {
  color: black;
  pointer-events: none;
  cursor: default;
}
</style>
```